# ReadMe link to OS that package binary does not exist for (CRAN)

Tags: r, package

I have a package that will not build on Mac as a binary but can still built if done with source.  The intended audience for this package is likely not familiar with command line and I want to make it as easy on them as possible.  I have a webpage explaining how to build from source but wanted it to be more prominent on CRAN as with the [RCurl package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) which doesn't have a binary for Windows.

How can I do this link to a ReadMe or is this able to be done for RCurl because it's one of the R core members that's maintaining it?

Comment: RCurl has a large list of packages that depend on it and the Windows binary is made available on Prof. Ripley's website. And as the ReadMe link illustrates it is by no means the only package on CRAN that does not build three ways. I also do not think it is a requirement that packages build on all three trunks in the CRAN compilation suite. Over the years I have needed to build several CRAN packages from source on my Mac.

Comment: @DWin Yeah but the question is how to get the nice ReaMe link on the page for my package.  Right now it ([LINK](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/index.html)) says check log for mac users.  That's not that helpful to someone new to command line stuff where as Ripley's ReadMe is very helpful.  I put it in the pdf manual but it's less likely to be seen there.  I've had to build from source to but we (particularly you) are more experienced users.  I am marketing (if you will) to the non-user.  The unfortunate part is most my users I come in contact with are mac users.

Comment: If the target audience does not know how to check for the dependencies that are missing on CRAN (openNLP in this instance) and then build those from source, then they are just going to meet a different stumbling block than the one they are getting now and are likely to be even less prepared to deal with it. Most of them will not know they also need to acquire the proper version of XCode for installation, and it will just add to the volume on R-SIG-Mac or R-help. The MacGUI makes it really easy to do these installs, but some people just never read the manual.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying hard to ease these people in (I come from the qualitative field where the command line tends to be scarier to people).  In the next version of qdap the [manual](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/qdap.pdf) directs mac users to a [help page](http://trinker.github.com/qdap_install/installation) explaining this.  Maybe the answer is I've done enough and if they don't get it then it's not meant to be but I remember as a new R user how helpful the RCurl (and at that time XML) ReadMe was for me to get these packages on Windows.  I may have become frustrated otherwise.

Comment: The ReadMe is specific to windows, it might be worth posting R-devel mailing list (at the risk of being harrassed for cross-posting), and suggesting a similar page within `http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/`.

Comment: I admit that sometimes cognoscenti assume too much. I get annoyed with instructions that read along the lines of: "Just make sure the PATH includes XYZ."  A) the newbs do not know how to read their PATH or the fact that the "PATH" may be different in various environments, and B if they do know how to query their PATH, they still may need to look at three different NIX websites to figure out how to (maybe) change it correctly. Were you thinking of providing extensive documentation to help the NIX-clue-needful population?

Comment: @mnel I think you've provided an answer.  Can you post as an answer and I'll check it.  Not sure how I'll proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a file called `INSTALL` in the same directory as the `DESCRIPTION` file and it will automatically be linked on CRAN.  For example, see the [CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) for the sqldf package -- its linked on the `Materials:` line.

EDIT:

Format of web page has changed and the INSTALL file is now listed on the `Materials:` line (was `Installation:` line previously).